# Windows 7 professional debug/checked to normal windows 7 professional

Tags: windows-7

I have accidentally upgraded my Windows using my university dreamspark cd-key. I did a search and understood that the debug/checked version have a bloatware which is for developers.

Does anyone know how to downgrade/remove to normal windows 7?

Comment: The downloads and distribution media that contain the checked build are clearly labeled as "Debug/Checked Build." You don't get it by accident just using a dreamspark key.

Comment: Well, I didn't know what debug/checked version is before upgrading.. So ya :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to wipe the drive and re-install there is no way to "downgrade". However, using a dreamspark key does not necessarily mean you are using the checked version of windows.

The checked version of windows will be considerably slower than the "normal" version has it has extra stuff in it to help developers making drivers for windows find bugs. If you are using the checked version I would recommend just biting the bullet and re-installing windows.

The Windows Event log, System log, Event 6009 has system information that includes the type, it states `Free` [for the regular build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[image]